# Capistrano "cap deploy:migrations" fails since it tries to run all migrations, not only the pending ones

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, mysql2

I try to deploy with "cap deploy:migrations" since I have 3 new migrations which need to be executed on live server. The result is:

```
executing "cd /home/martin/public_html/project/releases/20110905131238; bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
    servers: ["50.56.82.190"]
    [50.56.82.190] executing command
 ** [out :: 50.56.82.190] ==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
 ** [out :: 50.56.82.190] -- create_table(:users)
 ** [out :: 50.56.82.190] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 50.56.82.190] An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
 ** [out :: 50.56.82.190] 
 ** [out :: 50.56.82.190] Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists: CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `name` varchar(255), `email` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB
 ** [out :: 50.56.82.190] 
 ** [out :: 50.56.82.190] Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
 ** [out :: 50.56.82.190] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 5816ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/martin/public_html/project/releases/20110905131238; bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'" on 50.56.82.190
```

With a previous deploy I have created a working database on the live server. I created 3 new migrations (due to image upload with new gems carrierwave and rmagick) which I would like to deploy now. Obviously cap deploy:migrations tries to run all migrations from the first one, not just the pending ones.

My deploy.rb is:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
set :application, "otg.in"
set :domain, "otg.in"
set :user, "martin"
set :sudo_use, false
set :repository, "git@github.com:Martin118/otg.in.git"
set :local_repository,  '~/rails_projects/otg.in/.git'
set :port, 48000
set :deploy_to, "/home/martin/public_html/#{application}"
set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

server "50.56.82.190", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

after "deploy", "deploy:bundle_gems"
after "deploy:bundle_gems", "deploy:restart"
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:migrate"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

# Passenger
namespace :deploy do
     task :bundle_gems do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle install vendor/gems"
  end
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end

require 'whenever/capistrano'
```

I run rails 3.0.8, cap deploy:check gives me "You appear to have all necessary dependencies installed".

Any ideas? Or do you need more information?

Thanks for your help!

schema.rb on live is:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110130000344) do

  create_table "businesses", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "business_name"
    t.string   "postal_code"
    t.string   "business_email"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "fax"
    t.string   "web"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "address"
    t.integer  "city_id"
    t.integer  "state_id"
  end

  create_table "cities", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "state_id"
  end

  create_table "states", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "encrypted_password"
    t.string   "salt"
    t.boolean  "admin",              :default => false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true

end
```

Another update: select * from schema_migrations; on my development database gives me:

+----------------+
| version        |
+----------------+
| 20110112163009 |
| 20110113141953 |
| 20110113192958 |
| 20110114214158 |
| 20110115002206 |
| 20110119100832 |
| 20110120134443 |
| 20110127171331 |
| 20110127171427 |
| 20110127171921 |
| 20110127172903 |
| 20110127183252 |
| 20110129201949 |
| 20110129204159 |
| 20110129205833 |
| 20110130000344 |
| 20110808142844 |
| 20110809133339 |
| 20110809142303 |
| 20110809154349 |
| 20110810092306 |
| 20110810093531 |
| 20110812085010 |
+----------------+

But checking this with MySQL workbench I get (still development database):

Error: `project_development`.`schema_migrations`: table data is not editable because there is no primary key defined for the table

Also, the select * from schema_migrations on the productions database gives me just one migration (the last before I try to update):

+----------------+
| version        |
+----------------+
| 0              |
| 20110130000344 |
+----------------+

Has anyone an idea what happend here?

Thanks!

Comment: Go to your server and see what the schema_migrations table has as values.

Comment: What does `select * from schema_migrations;` return?

Comment: @ Mauricio and Dogbert: select * from schema_migrations shows:+----------------+
| version        |
+----------------+
| 0              |
| 20110130000344 |
+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.07 sec)

Comment: I have also added schema.rb from live server

Comment: 20110130000344 on live server was indeed the last migration before I added the new ones that create the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add the missing migrations into schema_migrations by hand. Somehow it seems that this table lost some of it's data. Anyhow, by adding the migrations that have already been done directly with "INSERT into schema_migrations (version) values ('2011....');", then cap deploy:migrations ran smoothly starting with just the new ones.